# Raster Tile Merge Performance of PostGIS 2.0

Tags: postgis, raster, tiles, performance, mosaic

I'm attempting to intersect Australian Census boundary polygons with the 1" SRTM DEM (10.5bn points across Australia), and output the result as a single raster image on the fly.

The DEM is stored in Postgres 9.2 x64 (with PostGIS 2.0) as 600x600 tiles with no overlap (i.e it's a mosaic)

I've hit the known performance issue in PostGIS 2.0 using ST_Union to merge the intersecting full and partial raster tiles into a single record.

For example: intersecting a 2,500 sq km polygon takes < 0.5s, which is excellent. But merging the resulting 18 rows into a single raster takes ~2 minutes.

Is there any other function in PostGIS 2.0 to allow for tiles to be merged without having to do any comparison between the overlapping pixels (which don't exist here as it's a mosaiced dataset)?

**Notes:**

- Plan B is to use gdal_merge in Python, but I'd prefer to keep this in
  the database for operational reasons.
- I've tried "ST_FasterUnion", thanks to this [excellent post](http://geospatialelucubrations.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/a-slow-yet-1000x-faster-alternative-to.html) by
  Pierre Racine, but haven't experienced a significant improvement in
  performance
- I'm aware of ST_Union performance improvements coming in PostGIS 2.1,
  but don't have a spare dev environment to deploy and test.
- Postgres has already been optimised for my machine and has plenty of
  RAM and buffers to utilise.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, no.  Not in 2.0.  2.1 should provide significant performance improvement over 2.0.

No matter what you attempt in the database with 2.0, you are limited by the number of times the raster objects are serialized/deserialized.

PostGIS 2.1 should be going beta in the next week or two (hopefully sooner than later).