# Merge raster tiles in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster

I have several raster tiles that are adjacent and non-overlapping, so they form a mosaic. I am trying to merge two adjacent rasters using PostGIS but am getting an error that they do not have the same alignment (pixel corner coordinates are not aligned). Can anyone tell me the correct way to combine the tiles into a single raster?

Comment: I believe this has been answered before, but st_union should be the right op... ex: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59952/raster-tile-merge-performance-of-postgis-2-0?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately ST_Union is returning the alignment error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ST_Resample() them before ST_Union() them. You can resample to one of them or to your own parameters.